# Let $\alpha$ be an increasing function on $[a,b]$. Show that $\int^a_b\alpha d \alpha = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha (b)^2 - \alpha(a)^2]$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

I am wanting to try to prove the question below, but there is a step that I can't get pass. I know that the proof is worthless if I assume incorrectly, and should have stopped proving from there, but I feel that I am close and possibly just missing a theorem or something that might be able to salvage the proof. But if ther is no way then I will just try a different attempt altogether.

Book: [here](https://www.studocu.com/en-za/document/university-of-south-africa/real-analysis/tutorial-notes-and-useful-questiond/17418810)

page: 166

I would really appreciate any help\insight you can offer.

**Question**

Let $\alpha$ be an increasing function on $[a,b]$ and suppose $\alpha \in R(\alpha )$ on $[a,b]$. Show that $\int^a_b\alpha d \alpha = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha (b)^2 - \alpha(a)^2]$

Note: $\alpha \in R(\alpha )$ this is showing that $\alpha$ is Riemann-integrable

**My attempt**

Let $P$ be a partition on $[a,b]$

Let as $\alpha$ is increasing, thus $\alpha(x) \leq \alpha(y)$ where $x<y$ for $x,y\in[a,b]$

Let $M_k = sup\{\alpha(x) | x_{k-1} \leq x \leq x_k\} = \alpha(x_k)$

Let $m_k = inf\{\alpha(x) | x_{k-1} \leq x \leq x_k\} = \alpha(x_{k-1})$

let $\Delta\alpha_k =  \alpha(x_k) - \alpha(x_{k-1})$

Now the upper Stieltjies integral: $U(P,\alpha,\alpha) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n M_k\Delta\alpha_k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\alpha(x_k)\Delta\alpha_k$

and the lower Stieltjies integral: $L(P,\alpha,\alpha) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n m_k\Delta\alpha_k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\alpha(x_{k-1})\Delta\alpha_k$

As $\alpha$ is Riemann-integrable thus the upper Stieltjies integral $=$ lower Stieltjies integral,

thus $\inf\{U(P,\alpha,\alpha)|$ where is P is a partition on $[a,b]\}$

$ = \sup\{L(P,\alpha,\alpha)|$ where is P is a partition on $[a,b]\}$

$ = \int^a_b\alpha d \alpha$

Let $\int^a_b\alpha d \alpha = \frac{1}{2}[U(P,\alpha,\alpha) + L(P,\alpha,\alpha)]$ <<< this is the problem step

$= \frac{1}{2}[\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\alpha(x_k)\Delta\alpha_k + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\alpha(x_{k-1})\Delta\alpha_k]$

$= \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n[\alpha(x_k)+\alpha(x_{k-1})]\Delta\alpha_k$

$= \frac{1}{2}[(\alpha(x_1) + \alpha(x_0))(\alpha(x_1)- \alpha(x_0))+ (\alpha(x_2) + \alpha(x_1))(\alpha(x_2)- \alpha(x_1))+\cdots]$

$= \frac{1}{2}[\alpha(x_1)^2 - \alpha(x_0)^2+ \alpha(x_2)^2 - \alpha(x_1)^2+\cdots]$

$= \frac{1}{2}[\alpha(x_{last})^2 - \alpha(x_0)^2] = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha(b)^2 - \alpha(a)^2]$

**the problem**

this $\int^a_b\alpha d \alpha = \frac{1}{2}[U(P,\alpha,\alpha) + L(P,\alpha,\alpha)]$

should be $\int^a_b\alpha d \alpha = \frac{1}{2}[\inf\{U(P,\alpha,\alpha)|$ for $P$ on $[a,b]\} + \sup\{L(P,\alpha,\alpha)| $for $P$ on $[a,b]\}]$

but I can't get rid on the $\inf$ and $\sup$. Is there away to do this?

Comment: What exactly are the hypotheses?  If you are given that $\alpha$ is an increasing function then it already follows that $\alpha$ is Riemann integrable.  The additional hypothesis that $\alpha$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ is redundant.  When you write $\alpha \in R(\alpha)$ do you mean that $\alpha$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$?  If this is given , then the problem is easy.  Otherwise you first have to establish that the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b \alpha \, d\alpha$ exists using only that $\alpha$ is increasing.

Comment: It also looks like you are not given that $\alpha$ is continuous.

Comment: @RRL, that is the full question, but I suppose its implied(stated in the beginning of the chapter), which I should have added, that $\alpha$ is real valued and bounded on the interval. I believe by the usage of $d \alpha$ that $\alpha$ is continuous

Comment: and α  is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to α

Comment: In order for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b f \, dg$ to exist then it is necessary that $f$ and $g$ not be discontinous at at any common point (either both from the right or both from the left).  If $\alpha$ is monotone then you can show that it is necessary for $\alpha$ to be continous if $\int_a^b \alpha \, d\alpha$ exists.

Comment: You have an overall sign error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can establish that the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b\alpha \, d\alpha$ exists by hypothesis or otherwise, then it is straightforward to show that

$$I= \int_a^b \alpha \, d\alpha = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha^2(b) - \alpha^2(a)]$$

Note that for any partition $a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$ we have

$$\frac{1}{2}[\alpha^2(b) - \alpha^2(a)]=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n[\alpha^2(x_j) - \alpha^2(x_{j-1})] =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n[\alpha(x_j) + \alpha(x_{j-1})][\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})] \\ = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha(x_j)[\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})] +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha(x_{j-1})[\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})] $$

Thus,

$$\left|\frac{1}{2}[\alpha^2(b) - \alpha^2(a)]-I\right|\leqslant \\ \frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha(x_j)[\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})]-I\right| +\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha(x_{j-1})[\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})]-I\right|$$

Note that the sums on the RHS are both Riemann-Stieltjes sums. Since the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, $I$, exists, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition such that

$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha(x_j)[\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})]-I\right|< \epsilon, \\\left|\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha(x_{j-1})[\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})]-I\right| < \epsilon$$

Hence, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$$\left|\frac{1}{2}[\alpha^2(b) - \alpha^2(a)]-I\right|< \epsilon,$$

and it follows that

$$I = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha^2(b) - \alpha^2(a)]$$

---

If $\alpha$ is increasing then it might have jump discontinuities in which case the RS integral of $\alpha $ with respect to $\alpha$ cannot exist.  To carry on we must assume that $\alpha$ is continuous.  Then it is not difficult to show that $\int_a^b\alpha \, d\alpha$ exists using both continuity and the fact that $\alpha$ is increasing (or more generally because it is of bounded variation).

Comment: (+1) A very simple and neat solution! Also, I guess what you point out in the addendum is one of the main reason that RS integral has become largely obsolete nowadays, in favor of the Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral or Henstock–Stieltjes integral.

Comment: thank you for your reply, if I used

$\lim_{\|P\|\to0} U(P,\alpha,\alpha) = \inf\{U(P,\alpha,\alpha)|$ where is P is a partition on $[a,b]\} = \int^a_b\alpha d \alpha$

 and $\lim_{\|P\|\to0} L(P,\alpha,\alpha) = \sup\{L(P,\alpha,\alpha)|$ where is P is a partition on $[a,b]\} = \int^a_b\alpha d \alpha$

ultimately ending up with $\int^a_b\alpha d \alpha = \lim_{\|P\|\to0} \frac{1}{2}(U+L) = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha^2(b) - \alpha^2(a)]$

Would this work similarly?

I guess the assumption that I make is that the limit = inf{}

Comment: @Reuben. If $\alpha$ is increasing AND continuous, then the right and left Riemann-Stieltjes sums in my proof are the upper and lower sums $U$ and $L$.

Comment: @RRL thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you have derived the product rule (or integration by parts) for Riemann–Stieltjes integrals like this one, then you can apply that to get:

$$
\mathrm{d}\alpha^2 = 2\alpha \mathrm{d}\alpha
$$

integration gives

$$
\int_a^b \alpha \mathrm{d}\alpha = \frac{1}{2} \int_a^b \mathrm{d}\alpha^2 = \frac{1}{2} (\alpha(b)^2 - \alpha(a)^2).
$$

If I were you, I would just copy the proof of the product rule from somewhere and go like this, not making my hands dirty with going back to definition directly.

Or here just plug in the $\alpha$ inside the integration by parts formula:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: Thank you for your reply, they have not covered actually solving it without doing the whole break down from the definitions so I guess I should be doing the same.